# Configuring AWS Lambda function with Zappa, unknown error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a Lambda function that will be used to essentially curl a web address every minute. In order to do that I'm using the python Requests library. The problem I'm running into is how do I install the package on AWS like I'm able to do locally.

I came across [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) and it looks to be what I need but I'm having issues configuring it. I went through the install steps for zappa, downloaded the aws-cli and setup the aws api credentials. This is the error message I'm getting -

```
$ zappa deploy production
Calling deploy for stage production..
Downloading and installing dependencies..
Packaging project as zip.
Error: Your app_function value is not a modular path. It needs to be in the format `your_module.your_app_object`.
```

In my `zappa_settings.json` -

```
{
    "production": {
        "app_function": "something", 
        "aws_region": "us-east-1", 
        "profile_name": "default", 
        "project_name": "something", 
        "runtime": "python2.7", 
        "s3_bucket": "company-lambda",
        "lamda_handler": "app.lambda_handler"
    }
}
```

In that directory I have -

- app.py
- zappa_settings.json

In `app.py` -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   print('hello')
```

Comment: Zappa is primarily used to 'host' Python WSGI apps on API Gateway and Lambda, so it's typically for migrating an existing Flask/Django app, and those would have app objects. Why don't you simply include the requests package in your uploaded ZIP file, per the example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html.

Comment: That works, thank you!

Comment: Great, I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zappa is primarily used to host Python WSGI apps on API Gateway and Lambda, so it's typically for migrating an existing Flask/Django app, and those would have app objects.

If you don't need that level of function, and simply want to include a few Python packages with your Lambda function, then simply include the packages in your uploaded ZIP file, per the [AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) that actually packages up requests, using:

```
pip install requests -t /path/to/project-dir
```